# Programmatically generate thumbnail CAP for small video

Tags: python, video, thumbnails, python-imaging-library

How can python make a simple cap for a video.

Ideia: take 9 snapshots for 9 even placed (on the timeline) times, and displace then in a JGP

How should I do this?

Is PIL the only way? (it's not going to be easy to do what I want, right?)

Aren't there any module (python seens to have GREAT modeles for almoust anything, or am I out of luck)

Example:

```
Movie lenght = 10 min
T1= snapshot of 1 min
T2= snapshot of 2 min
......
T9= snapshot of 9 min
   |   |
 T1| T2| T3
---+---+---
 T4| T5| T6
---+---+---
 T7| T8| T9
   |   |
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a quick change to something I've done some time ago, using ffmpeg for frame extraction and PIL to create the full thumbs image.

```
import os, sys
from PIL import Image

# Use "ffmpeg -i <videofile>" to get total length by parsing the error message
chout, chin, cherr = os.popen3("ffmpeg -i %s" % sys.argv[1])
out = cherr.read()
dp = out.index("Duration: ")
duration = out[dp+10:dp+out[dp:].index(",")]
hh, mm, ss = map(float, duration.split(":"))
total = (hh*60 + mm)*60 + ss

# Use "ffmpeg -i <videofile> -ss <start> frame<nn>.png" to extract 9 frames
for i in xrange(9):
    t = (i + 1) * total / 10
    os.system("ffmpeg -i %s -ss %0.3fs frame%i.png" % (sys.argv[1], t, i))

# Make a full 3x3 image by pasting the snapshots
full = None
for y in xrange(3):
    for x in xrange(3):
        img = Image.open("frame%i.png" % (y*3+x))
        w, h = img.size
        if full is None:
            full = Image.new("RGB", (w*3, h*3))
        full.paste(img, (x*w, y*h))

# Save result
full.save("thumbs.png")
```